# No results in kafka topic sink when applying tumble window aggregation in Flink Table API

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-table-api

I am using Flink 1.14 deployed by [lyft flink operator](https://github.com/lyft/flinkk8soperator)

I am trying to make tumble window aggregate with the Table  API, read from the transactions table source, and put the aggregate result by window into a new kafka topic

My source is a kafka topic from debezium

```
EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings.inStreamingMode();
TableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.create(settings);

    //this is the source
    tEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE transactions (\n" +
            " event_time TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'value.source.timestamp' VIRTUAL,\n"+
            "  transaction_time AS TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ(4001, 3),\n"+
            "  id INT PRIMARY KEY,\n" +
            "  transaction_status STRING,\n" +
            "  transaction_type STRING,\n" +
            "  merchant_id INT,\n" +
            "  WATERMARK FOR transaction_time AS transaction_time - INTERVAL '5' SECOND\n" +
            ") WITH (\n" +
            " 'debezium-json.schema-include' = 'true' ,\n" +
            " 'connector' = 'kafka',\n" +
            " 'topic' = 'dbserver1.inventory.transactions',\n" +
            " 'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap.kafka.svc:9092',\n" +
            " 'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup',\n" +
            " 'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',\n"+
            " 'format' = 'debezium-json'\n" +
            ")");
```

I do the tumble window and count the ids in the same window by:

```
public static Table report(Table transactions) {
    return transactions
            .window(Tumble.over(lit(2).minutes()).on($("transaction_time")).as("w"))
            .groupBy($("w"), $("transaction_status"))
            .select(
                    $("w").start().as("window_start"),
                    $("w").end().as("window_end"),
                    $("transaction_status"),
                    $("id").count().as("id_count"));
}
```

The sink is:

```
tEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE my_report (\n" +
            "window_start TIMESTAMP(3),\n"+
            "window_end TIMESTAMP(3)\n,"+
            "transaction_status STRING,\n" +
            " id_count BIGINT,\n" +
            " PRIMARY KEY (window_start) NOT ENFORCED\n"+
            ") WITH (\n" +
            " 'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',\n" +
            " 'topic' = 'dbserver1.inventory.my-window-sink',\n" +
            " 'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap.kafka.svc:9092',\n" +
            " 'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup',\n" +
            " 'key.format' = 'json',\n"+
            " 'value.format' = 'json'\n"+
            ")");
    Table transactions = tEnv.from("transactions");
    Table merchants = tEnv.from("merchants");
    report(transactions).executeInsert("my_report");
```

The problem is when I consume dbserver1.inventory.my-window-sink  `kubectl -n kafka exec my-cluster-kafka-0 -c kafka -i -t -- bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic dbserver1.inventory.my-window-sink --from-beginning` I don't get any results, I wait 2 minutes (the window size), insert into the transactions table and then wait again for 2 min and insert again also no results.
I don't know if I have a problem with my watermark

I am working with parallelism: 2

On the flink dashboard UI I can see that in the Details of GroupWindowAggregate task the Records Received is increased when I insert into the table but still, I can't see the results when I consume the topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what David thankfully answered, I was missing [table.exec.source.idle-timeout](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/config/#table-exec-source-idle-timeout) as a configuration of the streaming environment, a variable that checks if the source becomes idle.
The default value of the variable is 0 which means that it doesn't check if the source becomes idle. I made it 1000ms and that fixed it as it checks for that idle source condition and the watermarks are generated properly that way.
this won't probably affect regular streams that have consistent message ingestion into them but was the case for me as I was inserting records manually and hence the stream was idle at a lot of times

Answer (score 1):

With this line

```sql
transaction_time AS TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ(4001, 3)
```

you have given every event the same transaction time (4001), and with

```sql
WATERMARK FOR transaction_time AS transaction_time - INTERVAL '5' SECOND
```

you have arranged for the watermarks to depend on the transaction_time. With this arrangement, time is standing still, and the windows can never close.

As for "I wait 2 minutes (the window size)," this isn't how event time processing works. Assuming the timestamps and watermarks were actually moving forward, you would need to wait however long it takes to process 2 minutes worth of data.

Comment: Thanks for writing this but I edited the source table to use the event time attribute from debezium as the watermark (I was having issues with deserializing transaction_time type) as follows:
`event_time TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'value.source.timestamp' VIRTUAL`
`WATERMARK FOR event_time AS event_time - INTERVAL '5' SECOND`
and I made the window size to be 5 seconds, inserted into the table data worth of those 5 seconds or more and still don't get any results in the sink topic! what could be the problem?

Comment: Also, I have in the Watermark Details in Flink Dashboard **No Watermark (Watermarks are only available if EventTime is used)** in the two subtasks! how is that and I am defining watermark in the table create?!

Comment: With watermarks trailing 5 seconds behind the events, you're going to need at least 10 seconds worth of data to get any results from the first window.

Comment: the way I insert into the transactions table is to insert into MySQL db and then it's captured by debezium, flink reads from this debezium kafka topic, I inserted several times row by row and used a loop to insert 100 rows. I experimented using the time event to be
`origin_ts TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'value.ingestion-timestamp' VIRTUAL` and 
 `event_time TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'value.source.timestamp' VIRTUAL`
I edited the window size to be 1 second, with no delay in the watermark and still no results in the sink. Am I inserting data in a wrong way? something wrong with debezium time?

Comment: Why don’t you take a look in Kafka and see what you are getting from debezium?

Comment: I look in the Kafka topic of the transactions table and I am getting all events from debezium correctly, all the events from beginning are there.. the table contains 450 row now and all of them are in the topic with their timestamps